# Find the run_length of a series of number digits and output as tuple of (digit, count)

Tags: python

Given an integer I need to create a list of tuples such that in each tuple the first entry is a digit of the number and the second one its frequency. This should be done from the left of the number and the order of the digits is important. Eg `11122311` would lead to `[('1', 3), ('2', 2),('3',1),('1',2)]`.

I do not want to use an inbuilt function such as `groupby`.

I am trying to iterate through the elements of a string as long as they are the same and then cut these digits and iterate again until the list of strings gets the length zero. I can unfortunately not implement this successfully. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
def compress(n):
    L = []
    while len(str(n)) != 0:
        for i in range(len(str(n))):
            for j in range(len(str(n))):
                if str(n)[i] == str(n)[i+j]:
                    L.append((str(n)[i],j)) 
                    str(n) = str(n)[j:]
    return L            

print(compress(11122))
```

Comment: @Matiiss -- this is a question on run-length encoding rather than count frequency.

Comment: No, that's absolute count. This is a run length encoder; RLE.

Comment: `(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in  itertools.groupby(n)`

Comment: @DaniMesejo The question explicitly asks to not use `groupby` or other built-ins to do RLE.

Comment: Check out more_itertools *run_lenth* first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a simple run length encoder by keeping the previous character and keeping a count of the "run" - i.e. how many characters you've seen before it changes.

```py
def compress_rle(s):
    compressed = []
    
    if not s:
        return compressed
        
    previous_character = s[0]
    run = 0
    
    for character in s:
        if character != previous_character:
            compressed.append((previous_character, run))
            run = 0

        run += 1
        previous_character = character
        
    compressed.append((previous_character, run))
    return compressed

print(compress_rle('11122311'))
```

This outputs the same as you gave in your question:

```
[('1', 3), ('2', 2), ('3', 1), ('1', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `while` to handle the iteration better:

```
def compress(n):
    res = []
    length, index = len(n), 0

    while index < length:
        last = n[index]

        # while the current value is equal to the last iterate
        run_length = 0
        while index + run_length < length and n[index + run_length] == last:
            run_length += 1

        #  append the run
        res.append((last, run_length))

        # move index forward
        index += run_length

    return res

print(compress("11122311"))
```

**Output**

```
[('1', 3), ('2', 2), ('3', 1), ('1', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Run-length encoding by using tuples to track run count.

**Code**

```
def compress(n):
    s, runs = str(n), []
    for c in s:
        if not runs or runs[-1][0] != c: # different letter->start new empty substring
            runs.append((c, 0))          # new run count tuple
        runs[-1]  = (runs[-1][0], runs[-1][1] + 1)  # increment run count

    return runs
```

**Test**

```
print(compress(11122311))  # Out: [('1', 3), ('2', 2), ('3', 1), ('1', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by converting your input in string and then counting each  number. This is the probably the cleaner way

```
def compress(n):
    n = str(n)
    return [(n.count(c), c) for c in sorted(set(n))]
   
print(compress(11122))
```

Comment: Does this produce `[('1', 3), ('2', 2),('3',1),('1',2)]` when the input is `11122311`, as the OP wants?